# Question about Django InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When i was using Postman for API test. I found that if the file uploaded containing any Chinese character, the filename of the object `InMemoryUploadedFile` received server-side would be appended with an double quotation mark: `"`. I can not figure it out. I do not know why this happend. 
[image]

Below is the screeshot of the request:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the request being sent and the filename of the file being uploaded? If you upload a different file, does it show the same? A screenshot of the code of the model of that queryset would also help.

Comment: I have reedited the post with request screenshot. I have tried another different file. And it turns out the same. If a filename with chinese character included, the it will be the same case.

Comment: Maybe it is the problem with postman.

Comment: Look at the response content, there are hints about why DRF refused the request

Answer (score 1):

It was postman's problem. You could have used another client instead

Comment: Then, what caused the problem?